# Multiple host on AWS Ec2

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to deploy multiple Ruby on Rails application on an EC2 AMI on AWS and I need every application to be attached to a domain name

I think this first part is all for the Apache web server and passenger for the rails deployment.

What i was wondering is if i should use anything like a load balancer on my instance in order to deploy my apps properly and based on a Name-based Virtual Host.

One more thing.... can i deploy Rails 2.x and Rails 3.x applications on the same AMI, and is there any documentation on that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Apache and Passenger to run multiple Rails applications.  If you only have one instance, then you don't need a load balancer, and name-based virtual hosting is orthogonal to the use of a load balancer.  You can run Rails applications that require different versions on the one machine; there's probably no documentation because it's so trivial, you just install the various versions of Rails you need and if the application properly declares what version of Rails it needs, it'll all Just Work.